# Deriving the differential equations with solutions corresponding to classical orthogonal polynomials using the orthogonality condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, orthogonality

I'm trying to understand a bit more about the classical orthogonal polynomials that appear throughout quantum mechanics. My question is whether it is possible to derive the differential equations with solutions corresponding to the classical orthogonal polynomials, using only the orthogonality condition. For example, if I require that a set of functions, $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ are orthogonal on the interval $I=[0,\infty]$ under weighting function $w(x)=e^{-x}$,
$$\int_{I}w(x)f_{n}(x)f_{m}(x)dx=h_{n}\delta_{nm}$$
for some constant $h_{n}$,
is it possible to derive Laguerre's equation
$$xf_{n}''+(1-x)f_{n}'+nf_{n}=0$$
If so, is this the traditional historic approach, or were these functions discovered seperately, and then were coincidentally found to be orthogonal? Also, if anyone has any resources where they go through this process it would be massively appreciated, thanks.